# Configure Spring 4 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with custom ClassPathResource

Tags: java, spring, maven

How to configure PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with custom .properties files for different environments (production, dev, staging)? on deploy spring throws "Could not resolve placeholder 'property.placeholder' in string value "classpath:${property.placeholder}" "

here is my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
          <property.placeholder>_developer.properties</property.placeholder>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <property.placeholder>_staging.properties</property.placeholder>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <property.placeholder>_production.properties</property.placeholder>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

here is PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configuration

```
static @Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer myPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resourceLocations = new org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("${property.placeholder}")
    };
    p.setLocations(resourceLocations);
    return p;
}
```

it works in xml spring configuration but didn't work if I use java config. Have any idea how make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do what i want:

At first I add this plugin to builds section in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>1</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>src/main/resources/${property.placeholder}</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>2</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>
                    ${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties
                </outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

At second I modify PropertySourcesPlaceholder configuration in my spring config file:

```
static @Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer myPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p 
        = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resourceLocations 
        = new org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] {
            new ClassPathResource("application.properties")
    };
    p.setLocations(resourceLocations);
    return p;
}
```

And also I add this annotation to my spring config class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

So now I write env-dependent properties to different properties files (like "_developer.properties" or "_staging.properties") and when I build project with maven it has been copied to "application.properties", which I use in PropertySourcesPlaceholder configuration

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.getProperty()` to get the environment variable.

Sample code:

```
Environment env = new Environment(new ClassResourceLocator(ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()), System.getProperty("env"));
```

Create `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` Bean:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
{
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPropertySources(new MyPropertySources());
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

MyPropertySources.java

```
public class MyPropertySources implements PropertySources{
    private List<PropertySource<?>> sources = new ArrayList<>();

    public EnvironmentPropertySources()
    {
        Environment env = new Environment(new ClassResourceLocator(ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()), System.getProperty("env"));
        PropertySource<?> source = ...; 
        // create class that extends PropertySource<String> and get property values from Environment
        sources.add(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<PropertySource<?>> iterator() {
        return sources.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String name) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> get(String name) {
        return sources.get(0);
    }
}
```